# How to loop in multiple file in python and process it one by one

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to write a program that read multiple files and processes them in one loop.

I want to search for the id in all files and take the mark of a student.

My code is:

```
iD = int(input("Enter the your ID: "))
mathFile = open ('COMP2101.txt','r')
itFile = open ('STAT1001.txt','r')
bioFile = open ('BIOL2101.txt','r')

for line in mathFile and itFile and bioFile:
    line = line.rstrip()
    part = line.split(" ")
    studentId = int(part[0])

    if studentId == iD:
        mathMark = part[1]
        print("math",mathMark)

    if studentId == iD:
        itMark = part[1]
        print("it",itMark)

    if studentId == iD:
        bioMark = part[1]
        print("lbio",bioMark)


mathFile.close()
itFile.close()
bioFile.close()
```

How can I map the file name to `if` statement?

Comment: You can merge all files to one map and then search it in map

Comment: can you please explain more. Because  I try to use map function but does not work with me :(

Comment: Do you really need to do this with a single loop / `for` statement? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
filenames = {
    'Math': 'COMP2101.txt',
    'IT': 'STAT1001.txt',
    'Biology': 'BIOL2101.txt',
}
for subject, filename in filenames.items():
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            ...
            if studentId == iD:
                mark = part[1]
                print(subject, mark)
```

Comment: He wants to do it in *single* loop.

Comment: can you please tel me what wrong in my cod and how i can to improve it ?

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import izip_longest # zip_longest in Python 3

with open('COMP2101.txt') as f1, open('STAT1001.txt') as f2, open('BIOL2101.txt') as f3:
    for line_f1, line_f2, line_f3 in izip_longest(f1, f2, f3, fillvalue=<anything you want>):
        # code
```

> can you please tell me what is wrong in my code and how i can improve it?

Consider this demonstration in order to understand what's happening with your

```
for line in mathFile and itFile and bioFile:
```

loop:

```
>>> for x in [1,2] and [3,4] and [5,6]: print(x)
... 
5
6
```

because

```
>>> [1,2] and [3,4] and [5,6]
[5, 6]
```

How to improve it? Use my splendid answer, of course! :)

Comment: can you please tel me what wrong in my cod and how i can to improve it ?

Comment: What about if i change and with coma , does it work ?

Comment: @prog no, it will not. What's wrong with the solution I gave you?

Comment: @prog good, trying to understand what went wrong is the right approach. If you are unsure whether something works, you don't need to ask me however. Just try it!

Comment: Thank you. I will try :)